# how to fetch/load model.json and weight.bin from two different URL?

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, servicenow, tensorflow.js

I was going through [Save and load models- Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/save_load) documentation page to load/save and run models into browser. CDN version of tensorflow.js is **1.1.2**

Syntax to use for example

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://model-server.domain/download/model.json');
```

The documentation says:

> This loads a model from an http endpoint. After loading the json file the function will make requests for corresponding .bin files that the json file references.

But the system i am working doesn't allow two different file to have the same URL path, as each file is saved with an individual id.

So my question is, **how can I load/save the model.json and the weight.bin (https method) from two different URL addresses?**

Btw if `tf.loadFrozenModel (modelUrl, weightsManifestUrl, requestOption?)` could be used,then please let me know how to use it? Because, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load the model and the weights from 2 different locations, according to the [doc](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel), the following can be used:

```
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('http://model-server.domain/download/model.json', {weightPathPrefix: weigthsUrl});
```

Comment: hi.   i did something like: const myModel = await tf.loadLayersModel(  [link]("https://instance_name.com/nav_to.do?uri=sys_attachment.do?sys_id=735a52a0dbd5330093d88a1848961988") ,  [link](
 "https://instance_name.com/nav_to.do?uri=sys_attachment.do?sys_id=316a166cdb95330093d88a1848961960"));  but it was not working. can you kindly provide a code snippet. BTW, the link that you have provided doesn't mentions about this method. where exactly can i find it, please pin point?

Comment: No doubt that it didn't work because you didn't follow the syntax, I gave in the answer. The link I gave talks about an optional object parameter. One of the key of that object is `weightPathPrefix`. Please do follow the answer and do report an error only if it is not working !

Comment: hey ,sorry for my  lack of knowledge :(..     I next did       const model = await tf.loadLayersModel([link]('https://id=735a52a0dbd5330093d88a1848961988'),
  {weightPathPrefix: [link]('https://id=316a166cdb95330093d88a1848961960'),
  method: 'GET', headers: {'Authorization': 'Basic YWCraW46MTIzNA=',
                          'Accept':'application/json',
                         'Content-Type':'application/json'}
  }
                     );  
model.summary();
 which again didnt work for me :/ i was doing it on the doc page that you referred.Am i again doing anything wrong ,please help?